# Flush saveAll in JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Since there's a `saveAndFlush()`, is there a way to 
Flush the updated entities when using `saveAll()`?

I'm trying to update entities by batch.

Will really be a big help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can manually call `saveAll()` and then `flush()`.

Comment: Thank you for this! Why did I miss this :( haha.

Answer (score 7):

No need to manually call `flush()` after `saveAll()`, just create a `default` method. Eg of `Person`:

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, String> {
    default List<Person> saveAllAndFlush(Iterable<Person> iterable) {
        List<Person> list = saveAll(iterable);
        flush();
        return list;
    }
}
```